# Differentiating honorific passive and potential conjugations of 出る

Tags: meaning, verbs, conjugations

Given the following sentence structure, I am wondering how one differentiates the usage of 出る in the following.

> 明日のパーティーに出られますか？

The usage of the partial に and the られる suggests a honorific passive conjugation *Will you attend tomorrow's party?*, but by the same token, I suppose it could be the potential *Are you able to attend tomorrow's party?*

Also, how would this change if it was simply:

> 明日のパーティーに出ますか？

Comment: I reworded "polite passive" to "honorific passive" because I think that is a more common, or at least clearer way to refer to what you're talking about.

Comment: Related: [How to differentiate ～られる conjugation between passive form and potential form?](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/649/how-to-differentiate-%EF%BD%9E%E3%82%89%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B-conjugation-between-passive-form-and-potential-form?rq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This probably isn't the answer you were looking for, but: it has to be differentiated using context (via. the subject of the sentence, as well as  circumstance).

While this is probably pretty obvious, to break it out a little:

- If you say 「（太郎さん、）明日のパーティーに出られますか？」 to your coworker 太郎, it is pretty unambiguously the potential.
- If you say 「（先生、）明日のパーティーに出られますか？」 to your teacher, it is ambiguous.

This type of ambiguity is quite often resolved by context though (as one might expect):

> 「太郎はパーティーに出るけど、次郎先生はどうかな。」
> 「次郎先生もパーティーに出られる。」
>
> 「明日のパーティ、誰が出ますか？」
> 「次郎先生が出られます。」

A point here is that, in the cases it is ambiguous, it is often not ambiguous in a way that particularly matters:

- "No I can't" logically implies "no I won't"
- "Yes I will" logically implies "yes I can"
- "Yes I can" usually suggests "yes I will" unless specifically stated otherwise
- "No I won't" is probably the hardest response to deal with if you were asking about capability, and in this case you would probably just ask for clarification.