# 聞く and the passive

Tags: grammar, passive-voice

Without additional context, what is the meaning, or possible meanings of:

```
XにYを聞かれる
```

I know 聞く can mean both to hear/listen or to ask. Which interpretation is correct:

1. X is heard by Y
2. Y is heard by X
3. Y was asked (a question) by X

Or are multiple options are possible? I think (3) is at least possible, but I'm not sure if this statement is potentially ambiguous. My gut feeling is that を plays an important role here. Can anyone help shed more concrete understanding?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Without additional context...

1 is incorrect; に marks the doer/"culprit" of the passive verb (see also [my answer here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/651/78)).  So X cannot be the one acted upon.  Thus, only 2 or 3 are possible.  And without further context, it could be either, but I feel that 3 is more probable similar to if someone says to you 「聞きたいことあるんですけど」 ("There's something I need to <strike>*listen to*</strike> *ask you*").